# Nested Foreach List NetLogo

Tags: list, foreach, nested, netlogo

Hi,

In Netlogo v.6, I'm trying to calculate a time-weighted measure of a peer's cooperative behavior. The point is, I can't figure out exactly how to do a nested foreach in NetLogo.

My current approach:

1. setup a list: reputation_peer
2. setup a list: reputation_peer_list, of variable 1 (behavior) and variable 2 (time tick)
3. Each encounter, add reputation_list to reputation_peer, making the reputation_peer a list of lists
4. calculate the weighted reputation:

   - taking item 2 of each list in reputation_peer, which is the time tick of that encounter
   - and dividing it by the current time tick.
   - This gives a fraction: tick of that encounter/total time ticks
   - setup a list reputation_weighted
   - To weigh the reputations, multiply the time fraction with the first item of reputation_peer, which is the behavior variable
5. Then, I want to know the reputation_current, by taking all values from reputation_weighted and adding them up.

I'm messing around with the foreach function but I can't seem to figure it out.
How would such an approach be coded in Netlogo?

My current code is (setting reputation_peer myself to test it):

```
to calculate_reputation
    set reputation_peer [[8 4][9 2][10 3][11 2][14 1]]
    if ticks > 0 [
      foreach reputation_peer [x -> set reputation_peer_list list (item 0 x) ((item 1 x) / ticks )
      set reputation_peer_list_2 lput reputation_peer_list reputation_peer_list_2]
      foreach reputation_peer_list_2 [x -> set reputation_peer_list_list (list (item 0 x * item 1 x))]
      foreach reputation_peer_list_list [x -> set reputation_peer_current reputation_peer_current + x] 
    ]
end
```

I don't really know whether I'm doing it right, but mainly, this code seems a very bulky with all the list_list things going on. I'm guessing it could be a lot simpler.

Would greatly help me out if you guys have some tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're expecting as final output, but maybe this does what you need?

```
to calc-rep-2
  set reputation_peer [[8 4][9 2][10 3][11 2][14 1]]
  let weighted_rep_list []

  if ticks > 0 [
    foreach reputation_peer [ x ->
      ; Pull out the values from reputation_peer for ease of use
      let encounter_behavior item 0 x
      let encounter_time item 1 x

      ; Calculate the time fraction for the current item
      let time_fraction encounter_time / ticks

      ; Calculate the weighted reputations
      let weighted_rep encounter_behavior * time_fraction

      ; Add the weighted rep to the list of weighted reps
      set weighted_rep_list lput weighted_rep weighted_rep_list
    ]

    ; Now, weighted_rep_list is a list of weighted reputations
    print weighted_rep_list

    ; Get the sum of the list
    print sum weighted_rep_list
  ]  

  tick
end
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks a lot for your help! Your code brought me a step further. Just have a different issue now that I can't seem to solve. If you have time, maybe you can look it over. It's in the main question up top in the edit section.

Comment: @maria118code Hi Maria, glad it helped! It's probably worth starting a new question for your edit, as it's a separate issue. Actually, in the interest of helping others who may have similar problems to you, it's probably best that you don't fully remove your original code once it gets a working answer. I'd personally recommend you 'rollback' your edits so that your original question is shown (your  edits are tracked under the "edited x hours ago" link under your post) and start a new question.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable! For anyone interested, the other question is now posted under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720730/netlogo-list-updated-in-time